# Batch MYSQL inserts for performance in DB structure migration

Tags: mysql, database, performance, innodb

I need to restructure my MYSQL InnoDB database.

At the moment I have a `customer` table holding 3 product names.

I need to extract these names to a new `product` table. The `product` table should hold each name currently held in the `customer` table and be linked to the `customer` table via a new `customer_product` table. While the product names may not be unique, they don't have anything to do with each other, meaning for each `customer` there will need to be inserted 3 new entries into the `product` table and 3 new entries into the `customer_product` table.

So instead of this:

```
customer
| id | product_name_a | product_name_b | product_name_c |
```

I need this:

```
customer
| id |

customer_product
| customer_id | product_id | X3

product
| id | name | X3
```

I've written the following MYSQL procedure that works:

```
BEGIN
  DECLARE nbr_of_customers BIGINT(20);
  DECLARE customer_count BIGINT(20);
  DECLARE product_id BIGINT(20);
  DECLARE customer_id BIGINT(20);
  DECLARE product_name_a VARCHAR(500);
  DECLARE product_name_b VARCHAR(500);
  DECLARE product_name_c VARCHAR(500);

  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM customer INTO nbr_of_customers;
  SET customer_count = 0;
  SET product_id = 1;

  WHILE customer_count < nbr_of_customers DO
    SELECT
      customer.id,
      customer.product_name_a,
      customer.product_name_b,
      customer.product_name_c
    INTO
      customer_id,
      product_name_a,
      product_name_b,
      product_name_c
    FROM customer
    LIMIT customer_count,1;

    INSERT INTO product(id, name)
      VALUES(product_id, product_name_a);
    INSERT INTO customer_product(customer_id, product_id)
      VALUES(customer_id, product_id);
    SET product_id = product_id + 1;

    INSERT INTO product(id, name)
      VALUES(product_id, product_name_b);
    INSERT INTO customer_product(customer_id, product_id)
      VALUES(customer_id, product_id);
    SET product_id = product_id + 1;

    INSERT INTO product(id, name)
      VALUES(product_id, product_name_c);
    INSERT INTO customer_product(customer_id, product_id)
      VALUES(customer_id, product_id);
    SET product_id = product_id + 1;

    SET customer_count = customer_count + 1;
  END WHILE;
END;
```

---

**This is too slow.**

I've run this locally and estimate that my ~15k customers would take ~1h to complete. And my VPS server is far slower than that, so it could take upward to 10h to complete.

The problem seem to be the inserts taking a long time. I've would therefore like to store all the inserts during the procedure and execute them all in batch after the loop is complete and I know what to insert.

I there a way to perform all the ~100k inserts in batch to optimize performance, or is there a better way to do it?

---

**FINAL EDIT:**

I marked the correct solution based on that it did an excellent job of speeding up the process massively, which was the main focus of the question. In the end I ended up performing the migration using modified production code (in Java), due to the solution's limitations regarding not escaping the inserted strings.

Comment: Concatenate them all into `VALUES (product_id1, product_name1), (product_id2, product_name2), ...` in a single `INSERT` statement that you create with `PREPARE`.

Comment: There seems to be a problem with your whole approach. What if two customers have the same product? Your code will create different rows in the `product` table for each of them.

Comment: @Barmar those are just example tables I've chosen for the question because people are familiar with them; the actual tables are more complex and has nothing to do with customers or products, but the idea is the same.

Comment: I think my question is valid regardless of the domain. If whatever `product_name_X` translates to is not unique, you'll create lots of duplicates. Jon Wolski's answer looks like it merges all the duplicates by creating the `product` table first.

Comment: @Barmar Okey so it was a bad choice of tables names on my part. Different products don't have anything to do with each other. Instead of extracting `product_name_a`, `..._b`, `..._c` from `customer` to `product` you can think of it as extracting `first_name`, `middle_name`, `last_name` from `person` to `name`.

Comment: That's even weirder. Why would you have those in separate rows in the new table?

Comment: @Barmar The reason is completely irrelevant to my question and there can be any number of reasons. Mainly it is to be able to link more information to each name in the `name` table. E.g. when was the name issued? By whom? How old was the person when they learned to spell it? I also have to do with being able to link a person to any number of names in the future. But as I said, it's completely irrelevant to my question.

Comment: How duplicates should be handled is relevant. It affects whether Jon Wolski's answer is reasonable -- he assumes all the names will be unique.

Comment: @Barmar Fair enough, I can now see how that can be confusing and have updated the question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, use a cursor to process the results of a single query, rather than performing a separate query for each row.

Then concatenate the `VALUES` lists into strings that you execute using `PREPARE` and `EXECUTE`.

My code does the inserts in batches of 100 customers, because I expect there's a limit on the size of a query.

```
BEGIN
  DECLARE product_id BIGINT(20);
  DECLARE customer_id BIGINT(20);
  DECLARE product_name_a VARCHAR(500);
  DECLARE product_name_b VARCHAR(500);
  DECLARE product_name_c VARCHAR(500);
  DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
  DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR SELECT c.id, c.product_name_a, c.product_name_b, c.product_name_c FROM customer AS c;
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

  SET product_id = 1;

  OPEN cur;

  SET @product_values = '';
  SET @cp_values = '';

  read_loop: LOOP
    FETCH cur INTO customer_id, product_name_a, product_name_b, product_name_c;
    IF done THEN
      LEAVE read_loop;
    END IF;

    SET @product_values = CONCAT(@product_values, IF(@product_values != '', ',', ''), "(", product_id, ",'", product_name_a, "'), (", product_id + 1, ",'", product_name_b, "'), (", product_id + 2, ",'", product_name_c, "'), ");
    SET @cp_values = CONCAT(@cp_values, IF(@cp_values != '', ',', ''), "(", customer_id, ",", product_id, "), (", customer_id, ",", product_id + 1, "), (", customer_id, ",", product_id + 2, "),");

    SET product_id = product_id + 3;

    IF product_id % 300 = 1 -- insert every 100 customers
    THEN BEGIN
         SET @insert_product = CONCAT("INSERT INTO product(id, name) VALUES ", @product_values);
         PREPARE stmt1 FROM @insert_product;
         EXECUTE stmt1;

         SET @insert_cp = CONCAT("INSERT INTO customer_product(customer_id, product_id) VALUES ", @cp_values);
         PREPARE stmt2 FROM @insert_cp;
         EXECUTE stmt2;

         SET @product_values = '';
         SET @cp_values = '';
     END IF;

  END LOOP;

  IF @product_values != '' -- Process any remaining rows
  THEN BEGIN
       SET @insert_product = CONCAT("INSERT INTO product(id, name) VALUES ", @product_values);
       PREPARE stmt1 FROM @insert_product;
       EXECUTE stmt1;

       SET @insert_cp = CONCAT("INSERT INTO customer_product(customer_id, product_id) VALUES ", @cp_values);
       PREPARE stmt2 FROM @insert_cp;
       EXECUTE stmt2;

       SET @product_values = '';
       SET @cp_values = '';
   END IF;
END;
```

---

Beware that, using this solution, the product names will not be properly escaped before inserting. **This solution will therefore not work if any of the product names contains special characters, such as single quote `'`.**

Comment: Apart from a few syntax errors in your solution this worked great performance-wise. However, some of the names include special characters like backslash, and they are unescaped after reading them into a variable, leading to syntax errors when appending them to the insert statement. Is there a built-in way to escape all names before they are inserted into the product table?

Comment: I was worried about that, and hoped it wouldn't be a problem in your case. The built-in way is to use parameterized statements, but I don't think there's any way to do that in MySQL stored procedures when the number of parameters isn't known. I've done it in PHP using PDO, and it can be done in Python using `cursor.execute()`.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could do this in three separate inserts (instead of ~100K) as follows:

```
INSERT INTO customer_product (customer_id, product_id) 
SELECT customer.id as customer_id, product.id as product_id 
FROM customer 
  JOIN product on customer.product_name_a = product.name

INSERT INTO customer_product (customer_id, product_id) 
SELECT customer.id as customer_id, product.id as product_id 
FROM customer 
  JOIN product on customer.product_name_b = product.name


INSERT INTO customer_product (customer_id, product_id) 
SELECT customer.id as customer_id, product.id as product_id 
FROM customer 
  JOIN product on customer.product_name_c = product.name
```

Of course, you would have to set up your `product` table ahead of time, and you'd want to drop your de-normalized columns from your `customer` table after the fact.

This could be further sped up if you create an index on the `customer.product_name_X` columns (and possibly the `product.name` column, though it's so few, idk if it would be significant). `EXPLAIN` can help with that.